# Make seeds.rb file continue to seed even when 1 record couldn't be saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a seeds.rb that will seed my database.

When I run it, I get this error:

```
$ rake db:seed

rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::StringDataRightTruncation: ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(255)
: INSERT INTO "jobs" ("name", "location", "industry", "description") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"
```

Obviously a value for a `string` column is too long.

Instead of changing `string` columns to `text`, how can I change my `seeds.rb` file or anything else (possibly validations) to just not insert this row into the DB and continue on?

**seeds.rb**

```
Job.create([
  {name: "foo", location: "indiana", industry: "cooking", description: "Making lobster all day biznatch"},
  {name: "booz", location: "kentucky", industry: "chicken_mining", description: "We mine mad chickens so you can eat derrish KFC."},
  ...
])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `#create` instead of `#create!`, `ActiveRecord` will not raise in case of validation errors. In fact, `#create` returns false if the record was not created.

However, your case is a little bit different. The reason of the failure is not an ActiveRecord validation error (that in case of a bang method will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid`), but it's a database-level error. More specifically, it's a constraint violation that raises a `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid`.

This kind of exceptions cannot be bypassed, even if you use the non-bang version, because ActiveRecord considers it a low-level failure.

There are several possible solutions. First of all, you can perform the creations of each record one by one, and rescue the `RuntimeError(s)`.

```
attributes = [
  {name: "foo", location: "indiana", industry: "cooking", description: "Making lobster all day biznatch"},
  {name: "booz", location: "kentucky", industry: "chicken_mining", description: "We mine mad chickens so you can eat derrish KFC."},
  ...
]

attributes.each do |params|
  begin
    Job.create(params)
  rescue => e
    puts "Error #{e.message} with params #{params}"
  end
end
```

Additionally, you can add a size validation on the field in the ActiveRecord model, to make sure that the content will be pre-validated and ActiveRecord would not attempt to create and execute invalid SQL statements.

Generally speaking, this kind of errors should be considered a bug in your code, something you don't really want to silence. That's why even if you use the non-bang `create` version, ActiveRecord will complain.

You passed some invalid data to the database engine, and that should not happen unless you are ready to take the risk (and handle the exception).